# "Pre load" of Wordpress site very slow

Tags: mysql, apache, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site where when you type the domain and hit enter, it takes 1.5 - 4 seconds before the first piece of content even loads:

http://undergroundhealthreporter.com/

First, I have almost a dozen Wordpress sites on this host, and don't have that issue with any of them, so I don't believe it's a hosting issue.

Second, I know the site itself is content and script heavy, but the actual loading time of the site once the first piece of content appears isn't bad.

Third, I've experimented with various Wordpress caching plugins and while they help, nothing seems to eliminate that early loading issue.

I thought maybe it was slow DNS, but I also have sites with DNS hosted at GoDaddy that aren't this slow.

Any ideas of how to debug this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into tools like YSlow, which is a Firebug extension designed to help with that very question: http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/

I would throw a custom page inside your theme dir, with NO code in it, and see how long it takes your server to request the file outside the context of WP.  By this I mean pointing your browser at something like `http://undergroundhealthreporter.com/wp-content/themes/your_theme_dir/testpage.php`.  If this runs quickly you know the issue isn't with apache or with mysql or anything like that.

If it runs quickly, I'd then continue by adding in js and wp functions (maybe by making a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)), and watching for the point at which things slow down.

If it does not run quickly, unfortunately you need to dig deeper into the world of Apache logs and MySQL optimizations... but hopefully this is a good start.

Comment: Thank you - this step by step approach helps!